# Изменить id oбъектов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте,подскажите,как реализовать такое.
Есть элементы на странице

```
<p id="p1">1</p>
<p id="p2">2</p>
<p id="p3">3</p>
<p id="p4">4</p>
<p id="p5">5</p>
```

При нажатии на любой из них он удаляется,как сделать так,что бы id изменялись и всегда оставались по порядку?К примеру я удалил p3.  р4 стал p3  , а p5 стал p4
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @Etki,интересно просто,как такое сделать можно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'p', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $siblings = $this.siblings().filter('p');
  $this.remove();
  $siblings.each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'p' + (index + 1));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">1</p>
<p id="p2">2</p>
<p id="p3">3</p>
<p id="p4">4</p>
<p id="p5">5</p>
```

Только это абсолютно бессмысленно.

Answer (score 2):

id - такой же атрибут как остальные, если jQuery то можно так:

```
jQuery('p').click(function(){
 var number = jQuery(this).attr('id').split('p');
 var n = jQuery('p').lenght;
 for(i=number+1;i<n;i++){
  jQuery('p'+i).attr('id','p'+i);
 }
 jQuery(this).remove();
});
```

как-то так, код написан на скорую руку, но думаю идея ясна